# Como pegar todos os usuários logado no momento no Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Preciso fazer um loop com todos os usuários que estão logado no sistema no momento. Como eu poderia fazer isso?
Sei que com `auth()->check()` podemos saber se um usuário esta logado. Mais eu queria saber de todos que estão logado no momento. Existe uma forma?

Answer (score 1):

*Esta é uma maneira muito básica, mas espero que seja eficaz.*

**Passo 1**

Abra o arquivo `config/session.php` e altere o driver para o banco de dados (database).

**Passo 2**

Precisamos criar a tabela de sessões, então use o seguinte comando `artisan` -
 `php artisan session:table` para gerar o arquivo de migração.

**Passo 3**

Sobre esta migração recém gerada, você precisa adicionar uma nova coluna `user_id`, é assim podemos relacionar a `session` com um usuário, se esse usuário estiver logado, é claro.

Abra o arquivo `migrations/xxxx_xx_xx_xxxxxx_create_session_table.php` e adicione o seguinte dentro do `Schema::create`:

```
$t->integer('user_id')->nullable();
```

Aqui é como a `migration` completa deve estar:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSessionTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sessions', function($t) 
        {
            $t->string('id')->unique();
            $t->text('payload');
            $t->integer('last_activity');
            $t->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('sessions');
    }

}
```

**Passo 4**

Execute `composer dump-autoload` e `php artisan migrate`.

Nota: Se você não tem o Composer instalado globalmente, use apenas `php composer.phar dump-autoload`.

**Passo 5**

Salve o Modelo `Eloquent` em algum lugar em sua aplicação como `Session.php`.

Nota: O local recomendado para salvar isso está no diretório do aplicativo.

**Passo 6**

Agora você só precisa saber como usá-lo.

. . .

Uso

Coloque o seguinte `Session::updateCurrent();` em algum lugar em seu código, pois isso assegurará que a entrada da sessão para o usuário atual seja atualizada, apenas um exemplo, você pode colocá-lo em seu arquivo `app/routes.php`.

Obter todos os usuários

```
$all = Session::all();
```

Se você precisa verificar todos os usuários on-line por um determinado período, como 10 minutos, você precisa chamar o método `activity(:limit)`, assim:

```
$all = Session::activity(10)->get();
```

Nota: Este método pode ser usado em combinação com os métodos de guest() e/ou registered().

**Usuários convidados**

Pegue todos

```
$guests = Session::guests()->get();
Get the # of Guest users

$total = Session::guests()->count();
```

**Usuários registrados**

Pegue todos

```
$registered = Session::registered()->get();

foreach ($registered as $online) {
    // You can retrieve the user information using something like:
    var_dump($online->user->email);
}
```

Obter o número de usuários registrados

```
$total = Session::registered()->count();
```

**Modelo Eloquent**

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;

class Session extends Model 
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $table = 'sessions';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Returns the user that belongs to this entry.
     *
     * @return \Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser');
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the users within the given activity.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @param  int  $limit
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeActivity($query, $limit = 10)
    {
        $lastActivity = strtotime(Carbon::now()->subMinutes($limit));

        return $query->where('last_activity', '>=', $lastActivity);
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the guest users.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeGuests(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->whereNull('user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the registered users.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeRegistered(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->whereNotNull('user_id')->with('user');
    }

    /**
     * Updates the session of the current user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeUpdateCurrent(Builder $query)
    {
        $user = Sentinel::check();

        return $query->where('id', Session::getId())->update([
            'user_id' => $user ? $user->id : null
        ]);
    }
}
```

Alternativamente, você pode tentar [isso](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker).